# Postgres conver json string to date format

Tags: json, postgresql, date, type-conversion

I am pulling the close date from a json field using:
`data->>'closeDate' as PortalCloseDate` however this returns a string and I am trying to convert it to a date format. The date format in the string is YYYY-MM-DD so I tried `(data->>'closeDate')::date` but am getting the error: "ERROR: invalid input syntax for type date: "‎2020-‎12-‎09"" Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try bruteforcing on cleaning and casting the string to date:

```sql
select 
   cast(replace(cast(data->>'closeDate' as varchar), '"','') as date) as "closeDate" 
from table
```

Comment: when I try that it still returns the error : ERROR: invalid input syntax for type date: "‎2020-‎12-‎09"